# How to use jquery to change class in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to have an accordion slider (Enfold theme) open to a specific slide (unfortunately Enfold does not provide for that). I've tried everything I can think of starting with this code:

```
<script>
$( window ).load(function(){
$('.aviaccordion-inner').find('.aviaccordian-slide-     3').addClass('aviaccordian-active-slide');
 });
</script>
```

Then I also tried this code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

$( window ).load(function(){
$('.aviaccordion-inner').find('.aviaccordian-slide-    3').addClass('aviaccordian-active-slide');
});

});
</script>
```

I used "(window).load" etc. because I had no luck either with just simple "(document).ready". I made sure it was loading after the slider and jquery load. I also tried putting it in the body just before the slider loads.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to load a particular slide on 'load'?

The url for the website is: http://www.twinsupplies.net/2017/

Comment: Can I see what you wrote for the Html part?

Comment: Your question should include the HTML so that we can see what you are trying to target. Also I took a look at your website and I don't know where this slider is? I assumed you meant the accordian in the main banner, but it  doesn't use the `aviaccordion-inner` class, so where is the accordian you are trying to work on?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax to target an element by class and add a class to it in jQuery. Please give this a try and let me know what happens, but change '.classYouWantToTarget' to the class you're trying to target and 'classYouWantToAdd' to the class name you're trying to add.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.classYouWantToTarget').addClass('classYouWantToAdd');
    });
</script>
```

Another tactic I've used on dynamically appearing elements is something like this...

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //Name my interval to target later
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        //code from the first example
        $('.classYouWantToTarget').addClass('classYouWantToAdd');
        //See if your class has the class you're trying to add
        if($('.classYouWantToTarget').hasClass('classYouWantToAdd')) {
            //If so, clear the interval
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
   //Minimum acceptable interval time as of today
   }, 4);
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

You must have jQuery added to your site or you will get a "not a function" error in console. Add this script right before the end of your body tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the ideas. I forgot to mention that I had tried 'addClass' also but I did try it again just in case I missed something.  It gives me a "not a function" error until I put it in the following shell:
`
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    });
`
That didn't give an error but it did not work either. I wonder if I might be able to do this with php instead.  I'm surprised it has been so hard to do. Thank you for the ideas.