# Dropdown menu to switch class dinamically via JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this situation: in [this](http://palermotattooexpo.com/artisti/) page, there are some artists with some tattoo styles. My idea is to assign a class to every artist with, for example, the name of the style, create a dropdown menu with the name of the various styles and make sure that, when the various items are clicked, through JQuery, the assigned class is modified with another one that "highlights" all the artists with that particular style (for example, with a red border around the image).

Can you help me create a similar situation? Can you give me some ideas? I've been crazy for a week!

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Any code you've tried ?

Comment: For example, with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208227/how-to-use-jquery-to-change-class-in-wordpress/46209159#46209159 I managed to make the switch of the class, but I never managed to implement it all in a drop-down menu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tagging your photos with adequate classes, you can bind a callback to your dropdown list change event to reset all previous highlights and then give the highlight class to desired subselection based on a specific class.

I think it would be clearer with an example :

```js
// Dynamically build select options
let tatoos = [];

$('.tatoo').each(function(i, t) {
  let tatoo = t.className.replace('tatoo ', '');
  
  if(tatoos.indexOf(tatoo) < 0) tatoos.push(tatoo);
});

// Add options to the dropdown list
tatoos.sort().forEach(function(tatoo) {
  $('#tatoos').append(`<option value="${tatoo}">${tatoo}</option>`);
});

// Bind change event to monitor dropdown selection
$('#tatoos').change(function(ev) {
  let c = $(this).val();
  
  $('.tatoo').removeClass('highlight');
  if(c) {
    $('.' + c).addClass('highlight');
  }
});
```

```css
.tatoo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #999
}

.tatoo.highlight {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tatoos"><option value=""></option></select>
<div>
<div class="tatoo tatoo1">1</div>
<div class="tatoo tatoo1">1</div>
<div class="tatoo tatoo2">2</div>
<div class="tatoo tatoo1">1</div>
<div class="tatoo tatoo3">3</div>
<div class="tatoo tatoo2">2</div>
<div class="tatoo tatoo3">3</div>
</div>
```